# Compiler-generated move member functions on static data members

Tags: c++, oop, c++11

In Effective Modern C++, item 17 (**Understand special member function
generation**), Scott Meyers said that the generated special move member functions (move constructor and move assignment operator) *perform “memberwise moves” on the non-static data members of the class*.

> The move operations are generated only if they’re needed, and if they are generated, they perform “memberwise moves” on the non-static data members of the class.

I tried to understand the non-static condition but I couldn't, can anyone explain to me why can't they perform that on static data members?

Comment: Static data members are not part of any instances.

Comment: Copying or moving static members to themselves (they're shared by all instances) is a useless operation. Self-assignment and self-movement have no effect.

Comment: Change to a more basic book like C++ Primer if you don't understand what a static member is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because static members are not part of the created objects from that class. Though they don't need to be moved (or copied in case of copy constructor).

Answer (score 2):

I think it simply referres to static members, as here:

```
struct A{
   static int s; // static member, (not moved or copied when moving/copying an instance
   int w; // non-static member
};
```